# Nitrogen generator maximum flow check

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas

We have a N2 PSA unit with following specs

[image]
[image]

Now I have done some calculations as shown in the image. Assuming 0.8% of the air is (N2+inerts) rest being O2 can someone tell me that how 160CFM air flow by my compressor can give me 60NM3 of N2?

Ambient is taken to be 45celsius as this is written on our N2 flowmeter

Comment: 160CFM is 9600 cubic feet per hour; 80% N2 is 7680 cubic feet of Nitrogen per hour; 1 foot is 0.3 meter, so 7680 CF/hour is 207 cubic meters/hour before any losses... In my experience, CFM is measured relative to 1 atmosphere equivalent.